# Can Text Fields Auto-Recognize Phone Numbers and Links?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible for a text field to auto-recognize phone numbers and links?
I think I've seen such options somewhere, but I forget where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text views can, text fields cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the TextView to detect links in the properties editor.