# UITextView setting to detect phone numbers and hyperlinks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uitextview

Where is the setting for my `UITextView` to detect phone numbers and hyperlinks in Interface Builder? I think I've seen the option somewhere, but I forget where.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Text Fields Auto-Recognize Phone Numbers and Links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053778/can-text-fields-auto-recognize-phone-numbers-and-links)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a field in the `Text View Attributes` that reads `Detection`. Select whatever options you like from there -- Phone Numbers, Addresses, Events, Links.

Comment: It's in attribute view isn't it?

Comment: Ah I found it. Need to scroll around first

Answer (score 0):

here is my Code.

```
-(UITextView *) content {
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        _content.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
        _content.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _content.editable = NO;
        _content.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
        _content.text = @"my phone  is 18882222999 \r\n and my website is http://www.stackoverflow.com \r\n and I was born 1918-08-22\r\n";
    }
    return _content;
}
```