# iOS: Extract detected numbers and links from UITextView?

Tags: ios, url, uitextview, detection, phone-number

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067484/uitextview-setting-to-detect-phone-numbers-and-hyperlinks) and similar ones address how to detect phone numbers and links inside of a `UITextView`.

Once detected, is there a way to extract the detected numbers and links?

The goal is to use `UITextView` to detect numbers and links instead of rebuilding this logic.

To clarify, the ideal workflow is:

1. User enters text into `UITextView`.
2. `UITextView` detects numbers and links.
3. Extract numbers and links from text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextView really just makes the process of data detection easier to implement for user clickable links. If you are trying to extract and work with that data I would likely recommend implementing it to handle your specific use case. Data detection is luckily very straightforward.

```
let string = "www.google.com / (555) 123-4567"

let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.phoneNumber, .link]
let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.count)
detector.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: [], range: range) { result, _, _ in
   print(result)
}
```

Output:

```
Optional(<NSLinkCheckingResult: 0x6000031264c0>{0, 14}{http://www.google.com})
Optional(<NSPhoneNumberCheckingResult: 0x600003f384b0>{17, 14}{(555) 123-4567})
```